# Finding count of users with specific meta tag

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to integrate two plugins, and I'm kind of a WordPress noob but I'm finding my way...

I'm trying to find a count of users that have a specific meta tag.  I know I can get the meta tags by user and key by using the `get_user_meta` function, but I don't want to filter by user.

Example: I'm running through a loop of strings, and I want to get count of users that have the following usermeta record: key = "static key" and value="string from loop".

Is there a built-in function I am missing?  Or do I have to do this the hard way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this the hard way - running a query in the loop to get the count each time.